Base color of transmissive material doesn't apply to the entire object
I added a material to my bottle model with the transmission set to 1 and roughness to 0.01, with the base color set to a brown-orange.

The color only appears in the center, and the edges just reflect the HDRI.  When I look at the bottle in material preview the color is applied to the entire bottle.However, when I apply the same material to a sphere, the color is on the entire sphere.


I'm also using the bevel, subdivision surface and smooth by angle modifiers, but deleting them didn't help.

hello, it's not clear to me, you could please highlight the areas? Maybe also share your file?

the problem is in the edges of the bottle, how do i upload my blender file here?

The object was too thin, adding the Solidify modifier fixed it.
